# RecyclerView dissappearing items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have following issue.

`Fragment` with `RecyclerView` -> navigate to next fragment -> navigate back `popBackStack()` -> `RecyclerView` doesn't show items

It happens every other time(adapter instance inside `Fragment` always the same)

Adapter's `itemCount` always return's > 0 but I've checked that no `onCreateViewHolder/onBindViewHolder` method was called and 
also `LayoutManager` instance is present

This behavior happens on Samsung G7(don't know about other Samsung devices but everything is OK on Nexus, Xiaomi, LG)

```
setHasFixedSize(true)

adapter.setupData(content)
rv_test.adapter = adapter

/*setupData method*/
items.clear()
items.addAll(data)
notifyItemRangeInserted(0, data.size)

 <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    ...
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:overScrollMode="never"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                  app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
                    app:spanCount="2"
                    android:scrollbars="none"/>
...
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the full fragment code, and the full adapter code, as well as the XML for the fragment? I'm not sure what is happening from just these lines you have posted.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding data and notifying of an update before you are actually setting the adapter on the RecylerView.

Change:

```
adapter.setupData(content)
rv_test.adapter = adapter
```

To:

```
rv_test.adapter = adapter
adapter.setupData(content)
```

Comment: as I've written in the question my code first time(open next fragment and go back) works -> second time no -> then again works. Tried to set up adapter before and the same behavior